# Match file paths in HTML and Javascript Files

Tags: c#, regex

If anyone can help me having a lot of trouble with a regex expression

Basically I need a RegEx that can spot files in html,css,javascript
enclosed by single or double quotes

I have got this far `(\"|')([^"|'|\s]|\\"*)*\..*(\"|')`

I am using C#

See the link
[https://regex101.com/r/nga5yF/2](https://regex101.com/r/nga5yF/3)

But if you look at my tests at the bottom where I have multiple matches on a single line it fails.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: HTML is not regular so you should never use Regex on HTML.

Comment: I don't know C#. But this works for your example: [a-zA-Z0-9\/]+\.(png|jpg|js)

Comment: @wp78de Works perfect! thank you!! please add as answer and will accept!

Comment: @LennyD Alright, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `*` use the non-greedy or lazy `*?` quantifier to match an unlimited number of repetitions, but in a non-greedy way. (i.e. take the shortest match).

Also, you forgot to exclude whitespace and quotes in the part after requiring a dot to be included.

Test this version of the regex:

```
(?<quote>\"|\')(?<file>[^\"\'\s]*?\.[^\"\'\s]*?)\k<quote>
```

https://regex101.com/r/wTXhaM/1

Further improvements:

- Use named capturing groups.
- Use a back reference at end of pattern to match double quote or single quote depending on beginning of string.

---

Or if you want to also match filenames where single and double quotes are mixed use this variant:

```
(?:\"|\')(?<file>[^\"\'\s]*?\.[^\"\'\s]*?)(?:\"|\')
```

- Use named capturing group for filename.
- Use non-capturing groups for quotes

https://regex101.com/r/uM2Qfd/1

Answer (score 2):

We can use a negated character class for this:

```
['"][^'" ]+?\.[^'" ]*?['"]
```

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wKqPna/3)**

**Explanation**:

- everything between quotes, regardless of type, if there is a `.`